# How to make gpg prompt for passphrase on CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, gnupg, passphrase

The encryption tool of gnuPG package gpg prompts for passphrase using a GUI dialog box when invoked by a regular user, however when invoked by root it prompts on CLI. How to make it use the CLI even when invoked by a regular user.
 version:GnuPG 1.4.12

Answer (score 30):

On a debian box:

```
sudo apt install pinentry-tty
sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry
```

(and set it to pinentry-tty)

Comment: After much searching, this is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the best method, but the answer could be improved with a little explanation

Comment: This will change pinentry mode system-wide for all accounts on your device which might not be desirable. Providing pinentry option to gpg-agent or to single invocation of gpg does not impact the whole system

Comment: A simpler one, in the second line: sudo update-alternatives --set pinentry /usr/bin/pinentry-tty

Answer (score 20):

This kind of password prompt is not done by gpg itself, but by the gpg-agent.

You can configure your gpg-agent which pinentry program should be used. There are options both when starting the agent and in the gpg-agent config file -- please have a glance at the man page.

So I see two options:

- Configure your gpg-agent to use the desired method
- Disable the gpg-agent; you can do that for a single gpg invocation by unsetting the environment variable `GPG_AGENT_INFO` like `GPG_AGENT_INFO="" gpg ...`. gpg used to have a `--no-use-agent` option, but this has been marked deprecated and has no functionality in recent gpg version.

Comment: I created ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf and wrote `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` in it.
Didn't work for me !
Using `gpg --no-use-agent` did the trick.

Comment: @MayankPundir this option is obsolete for some time now; I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: GPG_AGENT_INFO="" gpg ... worked for me, the --no-use-agent did not.  Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Use of GPG_AGENT_INFO is not working as of 2.1, since it has been obsoleted.

Comment: For MacOS, you can go to  > System Preferences > GPG Suite, then  disable both "Store in macOS keychain" and "Remember for ### seconds" AND "Delete stored OpenPGP passwords." That last part is super important because if your password is already stored in the keychain disabling the other 2 options won't be enough! Hope this helped, it took me a couple months after I updated gpg and I accidentally enabled these options before figuring out how to revert it just now. I'll also add a post below for easy visibility

Answer (score 18):

I'm on GPG 2.2.13, and the `gpg-agent` man page reads:

> You should always add the following lines to your `.bashrc` or whatever initialization file is used for all shell invocations:
>
> ```
> GPG_TTY=$(tty)
> export GPG_TTY
> ```
>
> It is important that this environment variable always reflects the output of the `tty` command. ...

This doesn't explain the "why" (I also don't understand the "why"), but setting this in my `.bashrc` worked: it caused my `gpg-agent` to ask for my passphrase via the `pinentry-curses` interface. I didn't need to set any other configuration (I don't even have a `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file).

**Edit:** it seems that this works whenever no `DISPLAY` is available, e.g. in an SSH session with no X11 forwarding. But when I'm on the desktop and `DISPLAY` is set, it still brings up the GUI dialog. `unset DISPLAY` (BASH) in this case makes it use curses instead of the GUI.

Comment: Works like a charm if pinentry is installed. The command could be even shorter: ```export GPG_TTY=$(tty)``` ;)

Answer (score 11):

In newer versions of gpg, >= 2.x, you can use this

```
stty -echo; gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --pinentry-mode loopback --decrypt filename; stty echo
```

The stty makes sure your password is not echoed as you enter it.
A tad smoother than fiddling with configs if all you want is a quicky on say a desktop workstation you ssh'd into.

You will need, though, pinentry `sudo apt install pinentry-curses` or possibly `sudo apt install pinentry`

It's a far cry from the olden days of gpg 1.x where all you needed was `--no-use-agent`.

Comment: In my case, just specifying `--pinentry-mode loopback` was enough and no `stty` was needed. Tested under `gpg 2.2.20` on Arch Linux.

Comment: GPG 2.2.27: `pinentry` is not required for this recipe

Comment: @ynn `stty` is not needed, it just makes your password not visible on screen

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following environment variable to disable the graphical prompt

```
export PINENTRY_USER_DATA="USE_CURSES=1"
```

Comment: Not working on Debian Stretch either (gnupg 2.1.18).

Comment: This works on macos

Answer (score 2):

If you're on MacOS and using `pinentry`, you can go to  > `System Preferences` > `GPG Suite`, then disable both

```
Store in macOS keychain
```

and

```
Remember for ### seconds
```

AND click the `Delete stored OpenPGP passwords` button.

Deleting OpenPGP passwords part is super important because if your password is already stored in the keychain, disabling the other 2 options won't be enough!

I tried most other things mentioned on this thread, including adding `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to `~/.bash_profile`, using `gpg --no-use-agent` (got the deprecated message, but still didn't work), looking at the `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` files (neither one really had anything that looked like it would change anything), and nothing really made the CLI `pinentry` GUI prompt for the password until I did this.

Hope this might help anyone in the future who runs into this problem! It took me a couple months after I updated gpg and accidentally enabled these options before figuring out how to revert them back just now.

To clarify, if you WANT pinentry to prompt you to enter your password anytime you're doing something that you want to verify with your PGP keys, make sure you don't have the options to remember your password enabled AND make sure you delete any PGP passwords you might have stored in macOS keychain.

EDIT: found a similar answer on Ask Different: [How to use GUI pinentry program for GPG](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239099)

Answer (score 0):

My requirements is to create the keys in a remote server thru SSH connection.

> My requirements are not about scripting everything

no one mention this approach. But it works for me and it satisfies my requirements:

1. create keys in a machine with X11 (UI) available

```
gpg2 --gen-key

...output omitted...
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
Your selection? 1
RSA keys may be between 1024 and 4096 bits long.
What keysize do you want? (2048) Enter
Requested keysize is 2048 bits
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
Key is valid for? (0) Enter
Key does not expire at all
Is this correct? (y/N) y

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: Abd Tm
Email address: abd@example.com
Comment: Enter
You selected this USER-ID:
    "Abd Tm <abd@example.com>"

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
```

2. Export keys:

```sh
# export private key
gpg2 --export-secret-keys --armor --output myfile abd@example.com

# export public key (same command above except --export arg)
gpg2 --export --armor --output myfile.pub abd@example.com
```

3. Copy the 2 files to the server where i want really to install the keys:

```sh
scp myfile* user@remote-server:/home/user
```

4. SSH to the remote-server and import the key

```sh
ssh user@remote-server

[user@remote-server] $ gpg2 --import /home/user/myfile
[user@remote-server] $ gpg2 --import /home/user/myfile.pub
```

5. Validate it works:

```sh
[user@remote-server] $ gpg2 --list-keys
```

Credits to [this article](https://terminaltwister.com/gpg2-export-import-revoke-keys/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above, and more.
The "--pinentry-mode loopback" option works.
This command I now use:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback -q -d file.gpg
```

I'm using gpg 2.2.27

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did the following and it worked:

1. Install the pinentry program:

```bash
sudo apt-get install pinentry-curses
```

Since I was using SSH Connection, `pinentry-curses` is recommended, you can install any other variant,

- pinentry-curses: For console or terminal-based environments.
- pinentry-gtk-2 or pinentry-gnome3: For GTK-based environments.
- pinentry-qt: For Qt-based environments.
- pinentry-tty: For basic TTYs.

2. Configure your gpg-agent.conf

Edit your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file, if there isn't one, create it, and then add the following line:

```bash
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

Change the path as per the variant you used.

3. Reload the GPG Agent

You can kill the existing agent, and restart it using the command below, it'll make sure it uses the right config

```bash
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

Now, you can try signing again and see if the password prompt comes in.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
gpg --batch --decrypt --passphrase-fd 0 gpgfile < passphrase-file
```

Comment: I had to add `--no-use-agent` on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 - otherwise you get error gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode\ngpg: error creating passphrase: invalid passphrase\ngpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: invalid passphrase